# Use a Variable for Range DataAnnotation Validator

Tags: model-view-controller, data-annotations

I am trying to simplify my validation of a data model.  I would like to use a variable to represent the upper bounds of a property for a DataAnnotation Range validator.  Like so.

```
namespace MvcGMDemo.Models
{
    public class Vehicle
    {
        private static const int year;
        //public Vehicle()
        //{
        //    year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        //}

        public int VehicleId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Vin { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Make { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range( DateTime.Now.Year - 5,  DateTime.Now.Year)]
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I can put a constant in but the code would have to be recompiled for each new year?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should build a custom validator for that. Somethign along these lines (you adjust to your situation):

```
public class RangeLast5Years : RangeAttribute
{
  public RangeLast5Years() :
    base(typeof(int), DateTime.Now.Year - 5, DateTime.Now.Year) { }
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
[RangeLast5Years]  
public int Year { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps, let me know if not. Thanks.